# not safe for concurrent use

Tags: java, android

What does the phrase,

> not safe for concurrent use

mean?

I've run into it several times in Android Documentation. Specifically with Uri.builder class:

> Helper class for building or manipulating URI references. Not safe for
>   concurrent use.
>
> An absolute hierarchical URI reference follows the pattern:
>   ://?#
>
> Relative URI references (which are always hierarchical) follow one of
>   two patterns: ?# or
>   //?#
>
> An opaque URI follows this pattern: :#
>
> Use buildUpon() to obtain a builder representing an existing URI.

Comment: It means you should not access the same instance on different threads

Answer (score 1):

It means that an instance of the class shouldn't be accessed by multiple threads at the same time. This is because the class's code doesn't do anything to protect its internal state during multi-thread access - e.g. by synchronising its method or class variable access. If you do want to share an instance between multiple instances then you need to do something to mediate access, such as placing code using the instance within a synchronised method or code block, or using some other mechanism (see the java.util.concurrent package).

Comment: Also, to understand proper this answer [here](https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiW74vfr7bUAhXHaxQKHfAXAeQQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.tutorialspoint.com%2Fjava%2Fjava_multithreading.htm&usg=AFQjCNGHTcVPbO5Cxz3I6rz0J7TALrS2KQ&sig2=x1WZ4x90tobXV87aXfhZYA)

Answer (score 0):

"Concurrent use" means "access at the same time by two differents programs/threads". "Not safe for concurrent use" means it's not thread-safe, i.e. if you access the object from differents threads, you could face undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

There's no synchronization provided across threads use it only in one thread